# incrementally add array in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, addition

I have a series of matrices in a list
mtxlist = [mtx1, mtx2, mtx3, mtx4.....mtxn]
I have tried to add a number of matrices using the following but I am getting the right answer

```
startNum = 1
endNum = 3

for i in range (startNum, endNum):
   a = GetMatrix('mtx'+ str(i)) # this gets the matrices from program
   a = a+GetMatrix('mtx'+ str(i))
```

I am keep getting the incorrect result

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Example

[image]

Requried answer:

[image]

Comment: Is your `matrix` contains integer numbers? Like this mtx1 = `[[1,2],[1,2]]`?  What's `a` and `b` for?   It's very vague from your samples.

Comment: sorry mate - it is just numbers where a and b are just their names.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the GetMatrix function is designed to take a string as input. Adding the string 'mtx' and the integer 'i' will probably yield an error.
Try replacing i with str(i).

Comment: agreed - thanks Sam